# I am trying to compute the closest cosine distance from s to p(3,-4).Even though the cosine function is within range i am getting math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, output, trigonometry

```
import math
data=[(1, 2), (3, 4), ((-1, 1), (6, 7), (0, 6), (-5, 8), (-1, -1),(6, 0), (1, -1) ]
data.sort(key = lambda x :math.acos(abs((x[0]*3)) +x[1]*(-4))) /math.sqrt(((float(x([0]-3))**2) +(float(x[1]) -(-4)) **2))))
```

I am getting math domain error

Comment: Your argument to `math.acos` is `abs((x[0]*3)) +x[1]*(-4))`, which is outside the range `[-1, +1]`. Whatever maths you're trying to do, you're getting it wrong.

Comment: When I am computing it manually, I am getting it within the range of [-1, 1]

Comment: But I want to compute it to the whole equation that is even after the division. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis, so your square root is of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you equalize the paranthesis.

Second, math.acos(X) takes value X in the inclusive range of [-1,1], which is not provided by the above code, hence the math domain error.

Edit:

```
>>> import math
>>> data=[(1, 2), (3, 4), (-1, 1), (6, 7), (0, 6), (-5, 8), (-1, -1),(6, 0), 
(1, -1) ]
>>> data.sort(key = lambda x:1 - (x[0] * 3 + x[1] * -4) / (math.sqrt(x[0]**2 
+ 9) * math.sqrt(x[1]**2 + 16)))
>>> data
[(6, 0), (1, -1), (-1, -1), (6, 7), (3, 4), (1, 2), (-1, 1), (-5, 8), (0, 6)]
```

Below are the cosine distance after sorting:

> 0.3291796067500631
>   0.4631245078068408
>   0.9233035011152629
>   1.1849000654084096
>   1.2916666666666667
>   1.3535533905932737
>   1.5368754921931593
>   1.9011838618956602
>   2.1094003924504583

Comment: So for the same values how do I compute cos inverse? Is there any way?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which basis have you calculated. Like why haven't you multiplied in the numerator?

Comment: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/cosdist.htm